# What exactly does sequenceNumberForOrdering do when putting records into a Kinesis stream with the Java SDK?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-kinesis

I'm a bit confused about the AWS docs for putting records to Kinesis stream here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_PutRecord.html#API_PutRecord_RequestSyntax

It says that setting `sequenceNumberForOrdering` should be used for guaranteeing order "for puts from the same client and to the same partition key".

The example at the very bottom of [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/developing-producers-with-sdk.html#kinesis-using-sdk-java-add-data-to-stream) is what confuses me:

1. What should be the initial value of the variable
   `sequenceNumberOfPreviousRecord`in that example? `"0"`?
2. Why does it not seem to matter for which partition key the previous record was put? (The loop in the example puts records for two different partition keys, 0 and 1.)

Maybe I just don't get it, but I think the docs could do a better job of explaining this.

Comment: A better example here ( at very end of blog ) - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/how-to-perform-ordered-data-replication-between-applications-by-using-amazon-dynamodb-streams/

Answer (score 4):

That's a strangely incomplete example. Doesn't show or discuss how `sequenceNumberOfPreviousRecordin` is initialized. I found a [slightly better example](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=143285) in aws forums, apparently the starting sequence number to use is `null`.

```
String sequenceNumberOfPreviousRecord = null;
for (int j = 0; j < 200; j++) {
  PutRecordRequest putRecordRequest = new PutRecordRequest();
  putRecordRequest.setStreamName(myStreamName);
  putRecordRequest.setData(ByteBuffer.wrap(String.format("%s-%d",testData, 200+j).getBytes()));
  putRecordRequest.setPartitionKey( String.format( "partitionKey-%d", j/5 )); 
  putRecordRequest.setSequenceNumberForOrdering( sequenceNumberOfPreviousRecord );
  PutRecordResult putRecordResult = kinesisClient.putRecord(putRecordRequest);
  sequenceNumberOfPreviousRecord = putRecordResult.getSequenceNumber();

  System.out.println("Successfully putrecord, partition key : " + putRecordRequest.getPartitionKey()
      + ", Data : " + String.format("%s-%d",testData, 200+j)
      + ", SequenceNumber : " + putRecordResult.getSequenceNumber()
      );
}
```

Your example's use of partition key is weird as well. Unless if there is a very skewed distribution of partition keys, keys 0 and 1 are very likely to end up in the same shard. In most cases you're best served using a random uuid to ensure distributing incoming records across your shards.

Comment: So what about my second question? Should setSequenceNumberForOrdering for a record in a loop be set to the sequence number of the previous record in the loop or the last record with the same partition key? The linked example sets the partition key to a constant value.